# How redirect 'Confirmation token invalid' on Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I configured my Rails application with devise :confirmable and after registration the user receives an email with the confirmation link. When the user click in this link a second time the token is invalid which is the expected behavior in my application. However, it sends the user to a page located at "app\views\devise\confirmations\new.html.erb" with an error 'Confirmation token is invalid' and what I want is to show that error(<%= devise_error_messages! %>), but in my Sign In Page. (Actually, there are two possible states: a) The token expired and the user is NOT confirmed so the user must ask for a token once again; b) The token expired and the user IS confirmed so the user must just sign in)

For this, I inherited the Devise::ConfirmationsController creating my own ConfirmationsController to override the show method so I can redirect to sign in page if there is any error as follows:

```
class ConfirmationsController  < Devise::ConfirmationsController

  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    super
  end

  def new
    super
  end

  def after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def show
    self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])

    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to
            after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
    else
        respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity){ render 'devise/sessions/new'  }
    end
  end

end
```

And in my routes.rb I have this configuration:

```
get "confirmations/show"

devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}, :controllers => {:confirmations => 'confirmations'}
(...)
```

It redirects properly to the sign in page, but I **can't** pass the error(s) present in resources.errors to the sign in page doesn't matter how **hard** I try. How can I solve this problem?

Btw, my user model is configured in this way:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

Comment: If all you are doing is overriding one method, you don't have to define the other methods which only call `super`. If the method doesn't exist in your subclass, it will automatically call the superclass method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is change in confirmation_instructions.html.erb

Just replace this line

```
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token =>  @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

with  this

```
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token) %></p>
```

That's it.

Comment: Your answer worked for me, I had the problem described here, I think it should be accepted as correct.