# Devise Confirmable behavior when user clicks "confirmation" link more than once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm using Devise confirmable. I'm having an issue whereby if the user clicks on the confirmation link more than once (i.e. if the user forgot they already confirmed or whatever) they get a nasty error:

```
NoMethodError at /confirmation
undefined method `new_user_registration_path' for  <ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x007fe739a40510>
```

This is the confirmation link:

```
<%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@user, host: @host, confirmation_token: @user.confirmation_token) %>
```

Ideal behavior would flash[:alert] = "You've already confirmed" + a redirect to login page.

I tried creating my own `confirmations_controller.rb` and messing with the routes, but did not have any success.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 3):

By default Devise treats a user's repeated arrival at the confirmation page (with the same confirmation_token) as an error condition.  I think the easiest way to avoid the message is to override the `pending_any_confirmation` method in Devise::Models::Confirmable.  Removing from that method the lines which flag it as an error condition should do the trick.

Assuming you have a User model, in your `app/models/user.rb` file, insert this:

```
private

def pending_any_confirmation
  if (!confirmed? || pending_reconfirmation?)
    yield
# else
#   self.errors.add(:email, :already_confirmed)
#   false
end
```

Note: I'm showing the commented lines so you can see what exactly in Devise's original method is being changed.  Your method instead might have just a single line: `yield if (!confirmed? || pending_reconfirmation?)`

Answer (score 1):

Solved it on my own after finding an almost identical question on SO: [How redirect 'Confirmation token invalid' on Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261840/how-redirect-confirmation-token-invalid-on-devise)

Copying the `confirmations_controller.rb` from devise wholesale into my app didn't work, but calling `super` for `create` et al. and then specifying a new `show` action worked.

```
class ConfirmationsController  < Devise::ConfirmationsController

  def show
    self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])

    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to
            after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Your account is already confirmed. Please login."
      redirect_to '/login'
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: There's one thing you can improve though. Since your controller inherits from Devise's controller, there is no need to specify all those actions and call `super`. If a class is missing a method, it will try to delegate that method call to the parent object. So you should remove all those actions that simply call `super`, leaving you with a simple controller, with just the `show` action.

Comment: If someone uses a bad or expired token, this solution will still direct them to the login page saying their account is already confirmed.  If you just display the `<%= devise_error_messages! %>` on the `confirmations/new` page then it will display the correct error message as written in the `config/locales/devise.en.yml` file.